# Is Angular rest authentication secure?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, authorization

I am looking to connect to a secure REST service via Angular and have found the official way to do this is to set the authentication ticket as follows:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'dhfkssksk';
```

However isn't this insecure as anyone can simply view the JavaScript and find out the auth code?

Comment: Well yes, the client can see the auth code, the point is that in theory no one else can (if you're using SSL)

Comment: what service your using?

Comment: .net Web API service

Comment: do you have a backend or only writing an angular frontend for that rest service?

Comment: the back end is .net mvc, but it is a spa.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that your client app is connecting directly to your backend api (i.e. no 3rd party services), then the short answer is **yes**.

However, there are a few considerations you need to take into account:

1. You must only send this ticket to your backend and nothing else. I.e. set an HTTP filter in angular that acts on every client-side request and only sends this Auth header if the URL matches your API url.
2. You need to use SSL, to protect the token during transmission.

Comment: I thought if he already has a backend, why not route all request through it instead of connecting a 3rd party service from client code?

Comment: He is not talking about a 3rd party service, I assummed his Angular app is trying to connect to his .NET Web Api service

Comment: But the issue I can see is that no matter where i end up sending the token, it will be available for anyone to view through the javascript in the page..

Comment: Only the current logged in user could see his/her own token. The idea is to create these tokens when the user logs in.

Comment: the user is not logging in. the client is a display screen hung up high on a wall. As soon as it is turned on it should connect to the web service. If someone got hold of the url it was connecting to then they would be able to see the token.

Comment: @coolblue2000 why would seeing the URL mean that they can see the token? The token should be sent in the body of the request to your api.

Comment: Because if they put the url in to the browser it would give them the angular page which would have the token in plain text in the javascript? or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: What is the problem with having _your_ client see _their_ own token? Their token belongs to them.